# Python : Correlation coefficient between two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, netcdf, python-xarray

Let's assume that we have two different 2D np.arrays

`a = (np.random.randint(25,30,1512000)).reshape(1050,1440)`

`b = (np.random.randint(20,25,1512000)).reshape(1050,1440)`

So, the dimension of `a` and `b` is `(1050,1440)`

I want to calculate the cross correlation coefficient between a and b at each grid point (i.e to create a new 2D array containing correlation coefficient values between a and b, with a dimension of (1050,1440).

Comment: something to always watch out for in xarray - the [automatic broadcasting](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.03.0/user-guide/computation.html#broadcasting-by-dimension-name) & [alignment](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.03.0/user-guide/computation.html#automatic-alignment) during computation. I expect your arrays have mis-aligned dimension names & coordinates. Please post a full [mre] - as it stands we don't have enough information to identify the issue. At least, print grid_a and b, and always provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking a question. Thanks!

Comment: Also, check out the docs for the two functions. [`np.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) interprets the second dimension as a set of variables and the first as observations. [`xr.corr`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.corr.html) similarly will take the element-wise correlation across all dims except one you specify with the keyword `dim`. I expect you have an alignment issue, but once you resolve that, you also need to make sure you're calculating the correlation along the correct axes.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've edited my post completely, to be more concise and more clear.

Comment: whoa - now they're not even DataArrays! this is a totally different question. appreciate the MRE though. Question I have is how to compute the correlation coefficient elementwise at all. you don't have any variability at the pixel level, so what is it you are calculating?

Comment: We can consider the 2D array as a matrix, I just want to calculate the correlation between each point grid from matrix a and matrix b.  I found this link, but it is for temporal correlation https://climate-cms.org/posts/2019-07-29-multi-apply-along-axis.html

Comment: but you need multiple observations to calculate the correlation. the fact that the reference is talking about correlation *across time* is important. You can't just look at the correlation between two values. You could get a single value, the correlation of the two datasets *across all points* but this would not result in a (1050, 1440) grid. Just one value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with nctoolkit. Assuming the files have the same grid, the following will work:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds1 = nc.open_data("file1.nc")
ds2 = nc.open_data("file2.nc")
ds_cor = nc.cor_space(ds1, ds2)
ds_cor.plot()
```

Likely the grids do not match, so you might want to regrid:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds1 = nc.open_data("file1.nc")
ds2 = nc.open_data("file2.nc")
# regrid ds1 to ds2's grid
ds1.regrid(ds2)
ds_cor = nc.cor_space(ds1, ds2)
ds_cor.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for clarification, but actually the two 2D grids are stored as variables not datasets. So, is there any tool in nctoolkit to do the same with variables ?

Comment: I was guessing your data structure. You might want to reword your question to state how the data was stored. My assumption was that it was in netCDF

Comment: Thanks Robert, I reworded my question, just to show that the two grids are stored as variables not .nc files.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "variables". You should state the python data type, dimensions etc.

Comment: For more clarification: First I read two netCDF files (one for model and the second for observation), each file contain many parameters. I need only temperature, so I assign temp1 temp2 as variables from each .nc file. I need to do the correlation for only the two assigned variables not the whole dataset in the .nc files. Each variable is a 2D array with dimension of (1050, 1440).